# Xcode simulator no crash but real device problems

Tags: xcode, wkwebview

I run my app in Xcode through the simulator and it builds with no crashes. When I run on real device it successfully builds but I get crash errors. Someone suggested it might be the cordova screen lock but I tried it without and still have problems.

Running on real device: a blinking screen or it keeps reloading the first screen, never to make it to the next one. Please help!

Here are the different lines I am seeing when compared to the simulator:

```
Metal API Validation Enabled

<UMP SDK> To enable debug mode for this device, set: UMPDebugSettings.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"___________________________________" ];

THREAD WARNING: ['CDVOrientation'] took '44.751953' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.

[Process] 0x10f003740 - [PID=1655] WebProcessProxy::didClose: (web process 0 crash)
[Process] 0x10f003740 - [PID=1655] WebProcessProxy::processDidTerminateOrFailedToLaunch: reason=4

[ProcessSuspension] 0x10e0042a0 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process because PID 0 is invalid
[ProcessSuspension] 0x10e0042a0 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=0, error: (null)
0x150842818 - [pageProxyID=13, webPageID=14, PID=1655] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 1655), reason 4

[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>

[ProcessSuspension] 0x10e004300 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Background Assertion' for process with PID=1655, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}

[Loading] 0x150842818 - [pageProxyID=13, webPageID=14, PID=1655] 
WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason=Crash

[XPC] Handle connection with error: Connection interrupted

[Process] 0x10f004110 - [PID=0] WebProcessProxy::didFinishLaunching: Invalid connection identifier (web process failed to launch)
[Process] 0x10f004110 - [PID=0] WebProcessProxy::processDidTerminateOrFailedToLaunch: reason=4
[Process] 0x150842818 - [pageProxyID=13, webPageID=14, PID=0] WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 0), reason 4

[ServicesDaemonManager] interruptionHandler is called. -[FontServicesDaemonManager connection]_block_invoke

[Process] 0x10f0048f0 - [PID=1682] WebProcessProxy::didClose: (web process 0 crash)
[Process] 0x10f0048f0 - [PID=1682] WebProcessProxy::processDidTerminateOrFailedToLaunch: reason=4

THREAD WARNING: ['AdMob'] took '30.550049' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
THREAD WARNING: ['Consent'] took '10.710205' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

We saw this issue on Xcode 14.2 where web views were not loading.
Our WKWebViews had Content Rule List set.
The root cause was it compiled the Content Rule List to the underlying chipset (non-Intel), instead of respecting the Rosetta.
This issue was not seen when Xcode was launched without Rosetta.